# appending to arrays won't work for my code, is there a bug somewhere or am I using it wrongly?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, append

The program I'm working on is supposed to append values input from a scanner to their respective arrays from a different method. However when using the code exampleArray.push(value);, it gives me an errors saying :" Error: cannot find symbol, symbol:   method push(java.lang.String)."
Am I doing anything wrong? Did I miss something? 
Code for the class:

```
public class Agenda
{
  public static String names[];
  public static int days[];
  public static int types[];
  public static int diffs[];
  public static int row;
  public Agenda()
  {
  }
  public void createA() throws IOException
 { 
    FileWriter nFile = new FileWriter("CurrentAgenda.txt", false);
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(nFile, false);
    output.println("Current Agenda");
   //clear out data file

    output.close();
    nFile.close();

    FileWriter dFile = new FileWriter("Data.txt", false);
    PrintWriter clear = new PrintWriter(dFile, false);
    clear.print("");
    clear.close();
    dFile.close();
    create();
  }
  public static void create() throws IOException
  { 
    System.out.println("Your file will be: CurrentAgenda.txt");
    System.out.println("Input types:");
    System.out.println("Name--> Characters: A-Z");
    System.out.println("Type/Summative=(3), Formative=(2), Extra=(1)--> Integer: 1-3");
    System.out.println("Days Until Deadline--> Integer: Any");
    System.out.println("Difficulty/Easy=(1), Medium=(2), Hard=(3)--> Integer: 1-3");
    System.out.println("Please input assignments:\n");
    String again;

    names = new String[100];
    days = new int[100];
    types = new int[100];
    diffs = new int[100];
    row=0;
   do{
      FileWriter data = new FileWriter("Data.txt", true); //putting data in table for append
      PrintWriter append = new PrintWriter(data, true);

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Please input assignment name: ");
      String name = input.nextLine();
      names[row] = name;
      append.print(name +",");

      System.out.println("Please input the number of days until the due date: ");
      int day = input.nextInt();
      days[row] = day;
      append.print(day + ",");

      System.out.println("Please input assignment type:");
      int type = input.nextInt(); 
      types[row] = type;
      append.print(type + ",");

      System.out.println("Please input the assignment difficulty: ");
      int diff = input.nextInt();
      diffs[row] = diff;
      append.println(diff);

      append.close();
      data.close();

      System.out.println("Would you like to add another item? Enter 'Yes' or 'No'");
      again = input.next();
      input.close();
      row++;

    }
    while(again.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")); 

    List<Items> work = new ArrayList<Items>();
    for(int count = 0; count<row; count++)
    {
      work.add(new Items((names[count]),(days[count]),(types[count]),(diffs[count])));
    }
    Collections.sort(work, new Comp1());

    FileWriter firstL = new FileWriter("CurrentAgenda.txt", true); //formats the Viewer file
    PrintWriter paste = new PrintWriter(firstL, true);
    paste.println("Do these Assignments in order:");
    paste.close();
    firstL.close();

    System.out.println("Sorted Assignment Entries: ");

    for(Items e:work)
    {
      FileWriter agenda = new FileWriter("CurrentAgenda.txt", true);
      PrintWriter add = new PrintWriter(agenda, true);
      add.println(e);
      add.close();
      agenda.close();
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }

  public static void add() throws IOException
  { 
    String again;
    do{
      FileWriter data = new FileWriter("Data.txt", true);
      PrintWriter append = new PrintWriter(data, true);

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Please input assignment name: ");
      String name = input.nextLine();
      names.push(name); 
      append.print(name +",");

      System.out.println("Please input the number of days until the due date: ");
      int day = input.nextInt(); 
      days.push(day);
      append.print(day + ",");

      System.out.println("Please input assignment type:");
      int type = input.nextInt(); 
      types.push(type);
      append.print(type + ",");

      System.out.println("Please input the assignment difficulty: ");
      int diff = input.nextInt();
      diffs.push(diff);
      append.println(diff);

      append.close();
      data.close();

      System.out.println("Would you like to add another item? Enter 'Yes' or 'No'");
      again = input.next();
      ++row;

    }
    while(again.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"));


    List<Items> work2 = new ArrayList<Items>();
    for(int count = 0; count<row; count++)
   {
      work2.add(new Items((names[count]),(days[count]),(types[count]),(diffs[count])));
    }

    Collections.sort(work2, new Comp1());

    FileWriter firstL = new FileWriter("CurrentAgenda.txt", false); 
    PrintWriter paste = new PrintWriter(firstL, false);
    paste.println("Current Agenda");
    paste.println("Do these Assignments in order:");
    paste.close();
    firstL.close();

    System.out.println("Sorted Assignment Entries: ");

    for(Items e:work2)
    {
      FileWriter agenda = new FileWriter("CurrentAgenda.txt", true);
      PrintWriter add = new PrintWriter(agenda, true);
      add.println(e);
      add.close();
      agenda.close();
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: There's no `push()` method defined on `Array` objects in Java.

Comment: Do you have any specific requirement to use array over arraylist?

Comment: I'm using a comparator that sorts and object with 4 values in their order so I decided to use an arrayslist. I didn't put in the Items class code in here sorry

Comment: @NatalieB - You have another problem here. You are using `nextLine()` after `nextInt() / next()` methods of `Scanner` (check the do while loop)

Comment: @TheLostMind- Are you refereeing to : again = input.next();  ?

Answer (score 1):

There is not push method for java arrays. Instead, you must set the value by using the index at which you want to set it. For example, you could set the first spot of the names array to Rob by saying:`names[0]="Rob";` You will have to know the index. For your situation, you can consider using a counter that starts at 0 and increments every time you save an assignment name.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's weird because when I looked up how to append to arrays thats what came up.

Comment: And yeah thats what I thought of doing earlier too, though I kept getting null point exception errors for that. I'll try again!

Comment: @NatalieB The reason you are getting a null pointer exception is because names is a String array. Since Strings are objects, the default value for every spot in the array is null. Try using a for loop to go through the whole loop and set the value to ""(empty string) or something similar.

Comment: thanks!, I'll give it a go! I hope it works, this has been giving me a headache

Comment: @NatalieB What you may have saw was a data structure called a `Stack`, it can be implemented as an array and it has `push()` and `pop()` functions

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using standard arrays. Your compiler is correct there is no `push` method for a standard array.

## But there is a different array-like type you can use.

Try using an `ArrayDeque` (documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html)). It has the push method you're looking for.

You just have to remember that they get initialized a little differently than an array.

Instead of

```
String[] array = new String[50];
```

You use

```
ArrayDeque<String> array = new ArrayDeque<>(50);
```

The capacity argument for the constructor is optional. The size of an `ArrayDeque` can change, unlike a standard array.

You can then call your `push(E)` method just like you do in your code.

Comment: I'll check this out too!

Answer (score 0):

A `push()` method does not exist for arrays, if you want you can make a generic metod to push to your array something like:

```
<T> void push(T[] array, int index, T value) { 
      array[index] = value; 
}
```